# PInvoke C# to C++. Strange characters at the end of strings

Tags: dll, pinvoke, intptr

I read almost all the questions on this topic but I still have no solution.

This is the DLL function:

```cpp
int start(char* ipad, char* porta, char* codec, char* key_TX, char* key_RX){

FILE *myfile;
myfile = fopen("parameters.txt", "w");

fprintf(myfile, "Ip: %s\nPort: %d\nCodec: %s\nkeyTX: %s\nkeyRX: %s\n",ipad, porta, codec, key_TX, key_RX);

fclose(myfile); 
//Do something with my parameters
return 0;
}
```

In my C# application I already tried to pass string and StringBuilder parameters unsuccessfully. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684133/passing-c-sharp-data-type-parameters-to-dll-written-in-c) question was recommended the use of [PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120) and it suggests the use of IntPtr.
This is my wrapper C# class:

```c#
class MyPjMedia
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("PjLibDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "start", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int start( System.IntPtr ip, 
                                     System.IntPtr port, 
                                     System.IntPtr codec, 
                                     System.IntPtr key_TX, 
                                     System.IntPtr key_RX);


    public static int StartPjMedia()
    {
        string url = "127.0.0.1";
        string porta = "3700";
        string codec = "SPEEX/8000/1";
        string key_TX = "111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666";
        string key_RX = "111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666";

        IntPtr url_ptr = Marshal.StringToBSTR(url);
        IntPtr porta_ptr = Marshal.StringToBSTR(porta);
        IntPtr codec_ptr = Marshal.StringToBSTR(codec);
        IntPtr key_TX_ptr = Marshal.StringToBSTR(key_TX);
        IntPtr key_RX_ptr = Marshal.StringToBSTR(key_RX);

        int result = start(url_ptr, porta_ptr, codec_ptr, key_TX_ptr, key_RX_ptr);
        return result;
    }
}
```

In all cases the result is always the same: parameters.txt

```
Ip:    127.0.0.1
Porta: 3700
Codec: SPEEX/8000/1L
keyTX: 111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666ñ
keyRX: 111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666°
```

It's a Mobile application so i'm using .NET Compact Framework 3.5.

any suggestions? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer, so what you're doing might be perfectly ok, but two things look weird to me: 1. a `BSTR` is a Unicode string, and your C++ function takes a `char*` (should be `const`, btw). So you're printing Unicode strings using a pointer to an ANSI string. 2. BSTR is not guaranteed to be zero terminated - its length is stored before the characters array. So the printf might go beyond the original string, until it reaches a (ramdom) NULL. Again, this might not be the case, just my ~5 cents. No suggestions to offer...

Comment: Why are you converting your strings to BSTRs?  Also, you are leaking memory because you never freed the memory you allocated in StringToBSTR.  You should have been able to pass String or StringBuilder instance to char*, did you try using MarshalAs(LPStr)?

Comment: @eran In regards to null termination, see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b2d7d2c-47af-4389-a6b6-b01b7e915228(VS.85)

Comment: @tcarvin, you're right. I confused being able to contain nulls as part of the string (due to the length indicator) with not having to have a terminated one.

Comment: @tcarvin: I tried using [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder var but call to dll method causes a NotSupportedException

Comment: Ah, on Compact Framework it looks like the only CharSets are Unicode and Auto http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.charset(v=vs.90).  If you need the data to be in Ansi format then you can convert the data into a byte buffer using System.Text.Encoding and then copy to data to using Marshal.Copy().  The question is, do you need the data to be Ansi?

Comment: Ok I found the solution. I've used StringBuilder and wchar_t into te dll. Then there is the conversion from wchar_t to char* and it works.
pjmedia library wants ansi string for input. Tnx to all :)